# Find least $N$ such $S_{N}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{N}$ is power if $2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> Let sequence $\{a_{n}\}$,$a_{1}=1,a_{2}=1,a_{3}=2,a_{4}=1,a_{5}=2,a_{6}=4,a_{7}=1,a_{8}=2,a_{9}=4,a_{10}=8,a_{11}=1,a_{12}=2,a_{13}=4,a_{14}=8,a_{15}=16,\cdots$
>   or$$1,1,2,1,2,4,1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8,16,1,2,4,8,16,32,\cdots$$
>   Find   least $N(>100)$ such $S_{N}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{N}$ is  powers of 2

I want to find the colosed $a_{N}$ ,But it not easy to find it

Comment: "colosed"?  Do you mean the closed form of $a_n$?  It is more worthwhile and straightforward to compute the $m$th partial sum after the $n$th block. Then you just need to find the first $(n,m)$ pair in lexicographic order (with a suitable constraint like $m<n$ or some such).

Answer (score 6):

Let $T_n$ represent the $n$th triangular number, so $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k$. Then it should be clear that

$$\begin{align}
S_{T_n} &= \sum_{k=1}^n (2^k-1)\\
 &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k\right)-n\\
 &= 2^{n+1}-(n+2)
\end{align}$$

Since we're looking at $N>100$, we know that $n+2$ is smaller than $2^{n+1}$. Therefore, between $S_{T_n}$ and $S_{T_{n+1}}$, the only power of $2$ available as a partial sum would be $2^{n+1}$. You need to find a case where $n+2$ is the type of number that is the result of a sum of the form $1+2+\cdots+2^j$, i.e., $n+2$ must be one less than a power of $2$.

Does that give you enough of a push in the right direction?